# Can you fix a laptop with a thick black line in the middle of it?

Tags: laptop, lcd, acer-aspire

So, my stupid stupid self dropped my Acer Aspire 7551 and now there is a long thick black vertical line on my screen, I really don't know what to do. Anything I could do?

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: It is possible to fix, but maybe not cost effective in a 9 year old laptop.  If you value it highly, back up your data and take it to a repair shop. If  its of very limited value you could try opening it and reseating the connectors - particularly the screen one - but laptops are not fun to work with, and if the screen is damaged rather then a loose connector this won't help.

Comment: Use an external monitor or TV if it bothers you.